# Google sign-in how to logout without revoking user connection

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

on the new Google identity API, I can not find documentation as to how to log-out a user besides using the [revoke method](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/revoke)

What is the method of just logging out a user, without breaking the connection to the application completely?

I am using JS in VUE.

Answer (score 0):

The new Google Identity Services library (aka [Sign in with Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) library) does not support user session tracking unlike the deprecated Google Sign-in library.

Developers are responsible to track the user sessions of their sites. See [Session state and Listeners](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#session_state_and_listeners) section.